Building my Angular app stores the assets in index.html inside a <script id="ng-state"> and breaks runtime configurability
Context
I have an Angular 18 application that needs to call an API.
In order to have runtime configurability of the API url to call, I use a json file named app.config.json inside my src/assets/ directory:
{
  "apiUrl": "http://localhost:80"
}

The angular.json config states:
[...]
"architect": {
  "build": {
    [...]
    "options": {
      [...]
      "assets": [
        "src/assets"
      ]
    }
  },
},

I load the app.config.json using a factory from the app.config.ts:

export function initConfig(appConfig: AppConfigService) {
  return () => appConfig.loadConfig();
}

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    [...],
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initConfig,
      deps: [AppConfigService],
      multi: true
    }
  ]

Here is the app-config.service.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppConfig } from './app-config.d';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfigService {
    private config: AppConfig | undefined;
    loaded = false;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    loadConfig(): void {
      this.http
        .get<AppConfig>('/assets/app.config.json')
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.config = data;
            this.loaded = true;
        });
    }
    
    getConfig(): AppConfig | undefined {
        return this.config;
    }
}

Description of the problem
In local dev all of this is working fine, but when I build using ng build then the contents of the app.config.json gets integrated into the index.html.
When I deploy the app into a IIS webserver and browse the home page, there is absolutely no call to http GET the /assets/app.config.json
When I change the apiUrl in app.config.json and reload, I still see the previous api url used in the calls to the backend, even if I restart the website in IIS.
As it may be useful, here is the web.config I'm using:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>

And here is the generated <script id="ng-state"> tag in index.html:
<script id="ng-state" type="application/json">{"3274596508":{"b":{"apiUrl":"http://localhost:80"},"h":{},"s":200,"st":"OK","u":"/assets/app.config.json","rt":"json"},"__nghData__":[{},{"n":{"4":"3f","11":"10f","18":"17f","25":"24f","32":"31f"}},{"n":{"2":"hfn","5":"hfn2"}},{"n":{"4":"3f","6":"5fnf"}},{"n":{"2":"1f"},"t":{"4":"t0"},"c":{"4":[{"i":"t0","r":1}]}},{"t":{"2":"t1"},"c":{"2":[{"i":"t1","r":1,"t":{"1":"t2","2":"t3"},"c":{"1":[{"i":"t3","r":1}],"2":[]}}]}},{"n":{"13":"11fnf"}},{"c":{"5":[{"i":"c1702196430","r":1}],"6":[]},"t":{"6":"t4"}}]}</script>

My questions

How come the ng build is baking the assets into the index.html? The assets are part of the dist folder built, and are deployed with the rest of the code, so I would think there is no need for this forced integration.
How is the code not using http GET to retrieve the config? Is ng build replacing these http.get calls with sourcing from the ng-state script?
How can I change that behavior? I want to be able to change my config at runtime, that is the whole point of the app.config.ts in the first place

I have found absolutely no info on the ng-state script tag and on that behavior from ng build. All the documentation I find is telling me to do exactly what I've done and presented here.
Edit
After posting the question I stumbled upon the 'prerender' option in angular.json and turned it to false:
This had the effect of not including the app.config.json data inside the index.html but now when I deploy to IIS I have a 403 Forbidden error...

do you have SSR enabled?

@NarenMurali the ssr option is set to: { "entry": "server.ts" } but disabling it in the past changed nothing. It probably was because of the prerender (See my edit) so disabling both might help. I'll try

I think its ok to leave it as is right, its not disturbing anyone, also the static value getting cached should not be an issue

@NarenMurali removing the ssr did not help, I still have a 403 Forbidden. Also I see I no longer have an index.html file but simply an index.csr.html in the build result

SSR will cache the request since its already making it on the server for SSR, that is why the request is not visible is my understanding. reference

@NarenMurali Thank you, I have solved my problem and posted the results in the answer

How come the ng build is baking the assets into the index.html?
This is part of the process called pre-rendering. This can be disabled using this option in the angular.json:
"architect": {
  [...]
  "build": {
    [...]
    "options": {
      "prerender": false
    },
  }
}

How is the code not using http GET to retrieve the config?
The code might have been trying to use the http get to retrieve the config, because Server-Side Rendering (SSR) was active. It can be disabled using this option in the angular.json:
"architect": {
  [...]
  "build": {
    [...]
    "options": {
      "ssr": false
    },
  }
}

How can I change that behavior?
Disabling both options at the same time has solved the problem and lets me see retrieval of the config, as well as correctly updates the values used from the config on page refresh.
